# my wifi router says 80Mhz at channel 44 -- how is this possible?

Tags: wireless-networking

From what I can see in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels), the 80Mhz wide channels starts are channel 36 until including channel 48. 
Or in other words, how would the 80Mhz wide channel be labeled -- by the starting channel, the middle one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

40-, 80-, and 160MHz-wide Wi-Fi channels are identified by which 20MHz-wide channel functions as the primary/control channel, where all 20MHz-wide transmissions for that BSS are transmitted. So channel 44 VHT80 means that for that BSS, 20MHz-wide transmission will happen on channel 44, 40MHz-wide transmissions will happen across channels 44+48, and 80MHz-wide transmissions will happen across channels 36+40+44+48. The IEEE 802.11 standard defines which channels can be aggregated with which other channels, so that saying "channel 44, VHT80" is not ambiguous.